# How to set calculate variable to property in class

Tags: c#

I have a following class and i want to set YearCreated = 2023-age how i can do it ?

```
public class Car
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Producent Producent { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public int YearCreated { get; set; } 
    public Engine Engine { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: `public Engine Engine { get; set; }` <-- Your `Car` class doesn't have an explicit constructor that ensures the `Engine` property is initialized correctly, but the `Engine` property's type isn't marked as `Engine?` (i.e. nullable) but just `Engine` (i.e. `[NotNull]`), so doing `new Car()` will result in an object whose type _incorrectly claims_ that `newCar.Engine` is not `null` when it really is. Just so you know. _Constructors are good_.

Comment: Side note: obviously you understand that `YearCreated` is the value that never changes, while `Age` changes over the course of the same year... I guess this is just an awkward requirement in the assignment rather than your choice.

Answer (score 3):

Here you can find details
[Using Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties)

*It will be something like*

```
 public class Car
    {
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public int YearCreated => DateTime.Now.Year - Age;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could turn YearCreated into an [expression-bodied property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#read-only-properties). See below for example.

Note that this makes the property read-only. If you need to be able to override the property, you will need to add a backing field and give the property a body.

```cs
public class Car
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Producent Producent { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public int YearCreated => 2023 - Age;
    public Engine Engine { get; set; }
}
```